# How do I set up a kiosk that uses java and plays a . jar file only?

Tags: java, minecraft, client, kiosk

If we had a untouched Ubuntu server, and we wanted to put on it, lets say: Minecraft and have it so that it ran Minecraft only... What steps would we take to make the dream reality? I mean setting up a Minecraft Server/Client as a kiosk shouldn't be that difficult, should it?

All in all, how do I set up a blank Ubuntu server that runs only Minecraft (or other jar file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this very easily using [Workbench](http://www.rapidrollout.com/workbench/), a web-based Linux configuration and build system created by my company, RapidRollout (I am the founder). Workbench has built-in support for configuring a Java application to run as a kiosk application like you describe. In fact, we made a YouTube video showing how to create a Space Invaders arcade console using Workbench, which you can watch [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=al9jqfmYOhQ). I think that is pretty close to what you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

-Forest

Comment: Wow this is a helpful app! I wonder why people don't use it more often?